# First reputation bar not shown in bottom graph

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

If [reputation points changed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=reputation) in the first day of a user account's existence, then the reputation points bar is now showing in the bottom graph:

[image: First reputation points]